# The priestly breastplate?

Tags: bigdei-kehunah

The stones used to determine God’s will in a particular situation?
How?

How are we to understand this and apply this for todays worship?

Try to make your answer as clear as possible,thank you

Comment: Please clarify the question. Consider also breaking it up into multiple questions. E.g. first ask how the stones indicated God's will, then ask separately if this has any bearing on our worship. Also consider adding what sort of bearing it may have and why you think it may have this bearing.

Answer (score 3):

We have not had the Urim Vetumim (the insert with the name of Hashem put into the Choshen) since the end of the first temple. The Choshen (with the stones) was commanded as part of the Bigdei Kehunah (priestly garments), so the high priest wore one without the insert during the second temple. Since we do not have a temple (yet) we cannot have anyone wear the priestly garments. We can learn about the stones and their meanings but that is all.

The procedure used and the miracle of the stones lighting up do not apply nowadays.

[Kohen Gadol as Divine Medium by Yaakov Bieler](http://text.rcarabbis.org/kohen-gadol-as-divine-medium-by-yaakov-bieler/)

> The view in the Talmud that during the second Temple, there was no
>   Urim VeTumim, just as actual prophecy ceased at about the same time,
>   probably had more to do with the level or lack thereof of the high
>   priests of the time, than the physical Choshen.

Comment: We have not had the Urim Vetumim since the end of the first temple. How do you know this? Rambam writes explicitly in Hil. Beit Habehira (4:1) that they had the urim v'tumim in the Second Temple.

Comment: "Since we do not have a temple (yet) we cannot have anyone wear the priestly garments" Why would one possibly related to the other?

Comment: "the miracle of the stones lighting up" Who says the stones lit up? Do you have any source for this? This answer is nothing but questionable (arguably wrong) assertions strung together.

Comment: @mevaqesh Consider the medrash of Eli consulting the Urim Vetumim abaout Chana and misreading the results as שכרה instead of כשרה

Comment: Where do you see anything about the stones lighting up? Maybe they somehow otherwise indicated.

Comment: @mevaqesh The madrash says that the individual letters lit up and were interpreted by the kohen. I do not have the source right now but this is currently from memory.

Comment: TTBOMK there is no such Midrash.

Comment: @mevaqesh http://text.rcarabbis.org/kohen-gadol-as-divine-medium-by-yaakov-bieler/ as an example of a source.

Comment: @mevaqesh [18] This latter view serves as the basis for the Vilna Gaon’s  hypothesis in Aderet Eliyahu on I Shmuel 1:13-16, that Eli’s accusation of Chana’s being drunk was due to a false solution of a message from the Urim VeTumim:

Comment: First of all, I know you did not make it up; rather it appears to be a common misconception that you are merely spreading; your link does nothing to question that assumption. Furthermore, the Gaon is not dependent on the letter lighting up. Your own link says "He (the High Priest Eli) inquired by means of his Urim VeTumim **and the letters that either bulged out or** lit up were: “Heh”, “Chuf”, “Shin” and “Reish.” And he unscrambled them to means “Shikora” (a drunken woman)—“Shin”, “Chuf”, “Reish”, “Heh”; but the true solution was “Kesheira” (worthy, appropriate) [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] “Chuf”, “Shin”, “Reish”, “Heh”. I will note, that even were the claim about the Gra true (which it does not appear to be), it is important to distinguish between something that is a fact, something that a Midrash says, and something that may or may not be implied by one Acharon.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to the question of "how", [here](https://rabbibuchwald.njop.org/2014/02/03/tetzaveh-5774-2014/) is some explanation

> The אוּרִים ותוּמִים [sic], Urim V’tumim, served as a means of communicating with G-d. Rashi states, in Yomah 73b, that the High Priest could ask questions of G-d through the אוּרִים ותוּמִים [sic], and the letters that were etched in the stones would light up, providing answers to the questions asked on behalf of the People of Israel.

I'm not sure if this relates to current prayer, but I leave that to others.